# How can I find what cruises pass Iceland?

Tags: iceland, cruising

I've seen big cruise ships in the harbors of Iceland when I've been there. Now I'd like take a cruise somewhere from/to Iceland and wonder: what cruise ships stop in Iceland?

Where are some resources to research this online?

Comment: Keep in mind, most cruise line web sites and travel sites allow you to search by destination and or port city. If they are not as specific as Iceland, try Northern Europe.

Comment: I edited the question a bit to hopefully overcome the objections here, as I believe asking for places to find this kind of information ought to be on-topic.

Comment: @ZachLipton: see the OP's comment on my answer. It seems that you changed the interpretation of the question.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Sigh. Well I tried...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked: **How**, not **Which**, so I explain how I would search for such cruises:

I would use CruiseCritics: for example the advanced search in: https://www.cruisecritic.com/cruiseto/

Then you should put as port of call a port in Iceland. I would choose *Reykjavik*, as starting point. Wikipedia could help to find major ports, but take into consideration that cruise lines will often use different cities (with possibly just in parenthesis the real port name). This make very difficult to search in the very long drop down menus.

Then you submit your search (maybe specifying period and style). Pass quickly the cruises, and check if one do various stops in Iceland. This will give you hints for additional port-of-call searches. But in this case, I assume that nearly all cruises passing for Iceland, will reach also Reykjavik.

In such manner, you have the list of cruises that stop in Iceland.  Note: reading the result, you will find some duplicates: this because there are not "loop" cruises (every week or two weeks repeating the same route), and so the cruise companies will offer you various combined cruises (to Iceland, from Iceland, combined, half or entire world cruises).

In my experience, cruise critics (but the forum, ask there if you need very specific questions) tend to feature cruise ships, and not ferries which offer also cruise style cabins (but not all cruise facilities).  If your cruise style is ok for such type of travel, you can navigate in many more small ports, and meet Icelanders on the ferry.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder,  is was no troll, it was a valued user here who adjusted the question to what is acceptable on this site. If you do not want the changes you can roll back or edit it back to what it was. But you will find that the question will be closed as it did not (and then will not) fit this site.